# How to get value of ON/OFF switch

Tags: javascript, angular, web

I have On/Off switcher in my web project :

HTML:

```
<div  class="onoffswitch">
   <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" 
    id="myonoffswitch" checked>
   <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
     <span #onoffswitch class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
     <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
   </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "ON";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #93297E; color: #FFFFFF;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "OFF";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}
```

I want to know if the switcher is turned ON or OFF, I tried to get the value, using the next code, but it does not work:

```
getSwitcherValue(onoffswitch) {
   console.log("onoffswitch:"+onoffswitch.style.content);
}
```

Do you have any ideas how to get the value of on/off switcher?

Comment: Your whole "onoffswitch" concept looks inappropriate. I think there is no way to read the content value by E.style.content. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651739/how-to-access-css-generated-content-with-javascript

Comment: Why do you want to get value from `css` which is only responsible of the way the button looks? And which Angular version do you work with?

Comment: I believe this is what you want, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53930713/three-state-toggle-switch-in-angular .. You need to use radio input if you are making toggle switch..

Comment: @HarunYılmaz I want to check if switcher is on or off, angular2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Angular. So use [NgModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel).

```
<div  class="onoffswitch">
   <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="onOff" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" 
    id="myonoffswitch" checked>
   <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
     <span #onoffswitch class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
     <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
   </label>
</div>
```

And in your TS file:

```
public onOff = false;
```

You can now simply check `this.onOff` to see if your switch is "on" or not.

Answer (score 0):

use `onoffswitch.checked` instead of `onoffswitch.style.content`

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
    <div  class="onoffswitch">
   <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" 
    id="myonoffswitch" [(ngModel)]="isChecked">
   <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
     <span #onoffswitch class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
     <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
   </label>
</div>
```

And add `isChecked` into your ts file as a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular just use the its feature called two way binding

Ref : https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

for your problem solution:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wcaqhb

Comment: Thank you, your solution helped me

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this solution

**HTML file(eg app.component.html)**

```
<div  class="onoffswitch">
   <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" 
    id="myonoffswitch" [checked]="isSwitched"
  (change)="getSwitcherValue(isSwitched)">
   <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
     <span #onoffswitch class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
     <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
   </label>
</div>
```

**Ts File (app.component.ts)**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  isSwitched:boolean=true;
  getSwitcherValue(onoffswitch) {
    this.isSwitched=!this.isSwitched;
   console.log("onoffswitch:"+this.isSwitched);
}
}
```

**Css File(app.component.css)**

```
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "ON";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #93297E; color: #FFFFFF;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "OFF";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Here is the [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-angular-playground-awy9h4?file=app/app.component.html) link for reference